# Object Required - when trying to write to file

Tags: asp-classic

I get an Object Required error message when the following code runs. Can any help please, classic ASP isn't my strong point.

```vbs
<%
Function WriteToFile(strFile, strContent)
    Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' Second argument: 0 = reading, 1 = writing, 8 = appending
    ' Third argument: True = create file if it doesn't exist, false = dont
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, 8, True)
    objTextFile.Write strContent
    objTextFile.Close
    Set objTextFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function

Call WriteDataToFile("test.txt", "test")
%>
```

Comment: Might be permissions issue or AntiVirus on the server blocking the FileSystemObject altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure on which line you are getting the error, but try using Server.MapPath():

```
 Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(strFile), 8, True)
```

so that the application knows where to create/locate the file.